# Computation of the sum of a particular sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, summation

I am doing an exercise with the Gamma functions and I would like to compute the following:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\Gamma(n-k+\alpha)}{\Gamma(n-k+1)}=\sum_{k=1}^n(n-k+\alpha)(n-k+\alpha-1)\cdots(n-k+1),
\end{align}
where $\alpha$ is an integer larger than $1$.

Is it possible to compute the previous sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all arguments are positive integers, we can use factorials. Our sum becomes
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(n-k+\alpha-1)!}{(n-k)!}$$
Multiply by $\frac{(\alpha-1)!}{(\alpha-1)!}$ to get that our sum is equivalent to
$$(\alpha-1)!\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(n-k+\alpha-1)!}{(n-k)!(\alpha-1)!}$$
$$(\alpha-1)!\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n-k+\alpha-1}{\alpha-1}$$
We can reverse the bounds of summation to get that our sum is equivalent to
$$(\alpha-1)!\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{k+\alpha-1}{\alpha-1}$$
Now, we apply hockey-stick identity to simplify our expression to
$$(\alpha-1)!\binom{n+\alpha-1}{\alpha}$$
$$\frac{(\alpha-1)!(n+\alpha-1)!}{(\alpha)!(n-1)!}$$
$$\frac{(n+\alpha-1)!}{\alpha(n-1)!}$$

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know about the hockey stick identity. Thank you again!

Comment: I have another question! Do you think it is possible to compute also the same sum with each term multiplied by $k$? In other words do you think it is possible to compute $\sum_{k=1}^n k\frac{\Gamma(n-k+\alpha)}{\Gamma(n-k+1)}$ also?

Comment: You might want to make another post for a different question. I'm not sure if it is possible or not, but I'll try.

Comment: Ok! Thank you very much! I learned a lot from your answer!